# JavaScript regular expression with text constants

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a string: "cn=department9A,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9A,o=system". I want to pass every string that match the template as follows: "cn=department9X,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9X,o=system" where X - is any symbol (one or more).
Here is my code:

```
   var str = "cn=department9A,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9A,o=system";  
   var regexp = new RegExp("cn=department9+,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9+,o=system", "ig"); 
   console.log(regexp.test(str)) //false . but should be true
```

Please, help me to build a proper regex. Thanks!

Comment: Read the regexp documentation for the magic character which matches "X where X is any symbol". Hint: you'll find it on the first page. Hint 2: It's a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`9+` repeats the previous token that is `9` one or more times. Use  `9[A-Za-z\d]+` instead if you mean alphanumeric characters as symbols.

Example:

```
> var str = "cn=department9A,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9A,o=system";
undefined
> var regexp = new RegExp("cn=department9[A-Za-z\d]+,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9[A-Za-z\d]+,o=system", "ig");
undefined
> console.log(regexp.test(str))
true
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/33)

[image]

Comment: By any symbol I mean any digit characters and/or any alphanumeric character.
I tried your solution (I used 9.+) and it works for str from the question. But for some reasons it doesn't work for this test string: "cn=department9C8,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9C8,o=system".

Comment: @Rakesh Where did you get those images?

Comment: @Avinash From regexper

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
cn=department9[\S\w]+,ou=subDepartment22,ou=subDepartment9[\S\w]+,o=system
```

This regular expression will work for all the non-white space character or word at the given places

\S - Non white space character
\w - Word character